# Set null to a foreign key which is part of primary key

Tags: sql

Here's the problem: I have 2 tables, DEPARTMENT (Primary key: dname) and DEPARTMENT_LOCATION (Primary key: city, street, bldg, level), another table to represent the relationship between those 2 called DEPT_AT_LOC (Primary key: dname, city, street, bldg, level)

Obviously the primary key of DEPT_AT_LOC is the combination of foreign keys, and by definition of primary key they are NOT NULL. However, my lecturer demands that ON DELETE of a department name in DEPARTMENT table, the foreign key dname in DEPT_AT_LOC must be set to NULL???

Can anyone help me with this? I emailed the lecturer to ask but he insisted that there's a way to do that, say something related to candidate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a column named "id" (the candidate key) on DEPT_AT_LOC and make that column the primary key. Then you'll be able to set dname on DEP_AT_LOC to be nullified ON DELETE.

Your database will no longer ensure you never have duplicate DEPARTMENT -> DEPARTMENT_LOCATION connection records in DEP_AT_LOC. You would have to move that check up to your application layer.

On a side note, why does DEPT_AT_LOC contain columns (city, street, bldg, level) already in  DEPARTMENT_LOCATION?